# wait for unknown number of threads created by CreateThread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I need to create an unknown number of threads and at the end want to wait for all the created threads to finish their jobs. After searching, I could only get to wait for some known number of created threads using `WaitForMultipleObjects(. . .)` which expects pointer to an array of handles of created threads. The following code is an example of the scenario.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>

FILE* fp;
time_t start;

struct mydata{
    int a, b;
};

void myFn(mydata* p)
{
    fprintf(fp, "a = %d\n", p->a);
    fprintf(fp, "b = %d\n", p->b);
    delete p;
}

bool condition()
{
     if(time(0) - start >= 1)
        return false;
     return true;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    start = time(0);
    fopen_s(&fp, "outOfExe.txt", "w");
    mydata* dataToGive;
    int n = 0;
    while(condition())
    {
        n++;
        dataToGive = new mydata;
        dataToGive->a = 2*n;
        dataToGive->b = 4*n;
        HANDLE WINAPI handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)myFn, dataToGive, 0, NULL);
    }
}
```

The solution I could think of is to create an array of size equal to number of cores in CPU and at any given time execute at max of this number of threads. But for this I would require to develop a queuing mechanism etc. Is there some way to wait for all the created threads by the way shown in above example?

Comment: Any reason you can't use an array (or std::vector) to store the handles? also why not using std::thread?

Comment: I have written that as one of the solution - but was wondering if it could be done without use of array. And std::thread not supported in visual c++ 2008(right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int threadCount, a critical section, an event and WaitForSingleObject?

Lock the CS, create your threads, incing the threadCount, then unlock the CS and wait on the event.

In the thread function/method, do your stuff then, at the end, lock the CS, dec the threadCount.  If it is then 0, signal the event.  Unlock the CS and exit the thread.

No array, no vector, no, (sane), limit on the number of threads.

Comment: Care to explain "WaitForSingleObject?"

What I understood is to have a global count of threads and increment/decrement it acquiring a lock over it. At end of main thread just loop till the count becomes 0.

Comment: @BitManipulator Use CreateEvent at the start. When a thread sees that is the last one, it signals the Event with SetEvent. The main thread wait, using WaitForSingleObject, for the Event to be signaled.

Comment: @BitManipulator - what manuell says. Looping is a waste of CPU and memory bandwidth - waiting on the event uses none.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `std::vector` is definitely the way to do and doesn't require a queue or having a preset number of thread handles it can store. The code below will create all of the threads and then wait for all of them to finish.

```
std::vector<HANDLE> threadHandles;
while(condition())
{
    n++;
    dataToGive = new mydata;
    dataToGive->a = 2*n;
    dataToGive->b = 4*n;
    HANDLE handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)myFn, dataToGive, 0, NULL);
    if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        threadHandles.push_back(handle);
    }
}

::WaitForMultipleObjects(threadHandles.size(), &threadHandles[0], TRUE, INFINITE);
```

As noted by [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758133/martin-james) `WaitForMultipleObjects` limits the number of handles it can wait on to 64. If you need more than 64 thread this will not work.

Comment: WFMO has 64-handle limit :(

Comment: in case I am using vectors(or array), shouldn't I keep the number of threads equal to number of cores for efficiency reasons?

Comment: @MartinJames Ack! You are correct. I've updated my answer to address that.

Comment: @BitManipulator If the threads are always executing (i.e. not in a wait state) then yes you might reconsider launching so many simultaneously.

Comment: @BitManipulator - in your case, the threads could well finish before you start waiting - they are doing SFA :)  In the general case, where the threads do something useful, it all kinda depends on whether you make any blocking calls in the threads and how much L1 cache each uses.

Comment: And yes, the actual scenario will create near to 70K threads - not all running at one time, but total. At a single point of time I estimate near to 10 will be alive.

Comment: If you guarantee that you will never wait on more than 64 threads at the same time the example in my answer is likely the most straight forward approach.

Comment: Don't forget to call CloseHandle on each thread handle after WaitForMultipleObjects.